# How to find some string from another by some exact pattern

Tags: php, regex

Hello I want to find some string from text by matching a pattern of word and digit.

```
 <?php 
     $a = 'Annex II/8Annex III/101';
     preg_match_all('/\bII\/\b/', $a, $matches);
     print_r($matches[0]);
 ?>
```

I want to get the value 'II/8'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `\d` to capture a single digit after the `/`, and then use a lookahead to assert that the next character is not a digit:

```
 $a = 'Annex II/8Annex III/101';
 preg_match_all('#\bII/\d(?=\D)#', $a, $matches);
 print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
II/8
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2M8Ku)

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Working fine. But one issue is that i have more digit like 2 or 3 digit like 'II/12' so i want to get this. So how?